# R Aligning Dodge in Linegraph with Single Datapoints & Error Bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, position-dodge

I'm trying to make a similiar plot to this here:

[image]

but with the categories dodged, so that they are spread out over the x axis and the values of one category are not completely overlapped.

I tried to initialize the value of position_jitterdodge but that only works for the data points (geom_jitter), not for the line plot or errorbar...

```
df <- ToothGrowth
df$dose <- as.factor(df$dose)

df.summary <- df %>%
  group_by(supp,dose) %>%
  summarise(
    sd = sd(len, na.rm = TRUE),
    len = mean(len)
  )

ggplot(df, aes(dose, len)) +
  geom_jitter(
    aes(color = supp),
    position = position_jitter(0.2) # position_jitterdodge ?
  ) + 
  geom_line(
    aes(group = supp, color = supp),
    data = df.summary
  ) +
  geom_errorbar(
    aes(ymin = len-sd, ymax = len+sd, color = supp),
    data = df.summary, width = 0.2
  )+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can dodge the error bars and line as well

```
ggplot(df, aes(dose, len)) +
  geom_jitter(
    aes(color = supp),
    position = position_jitterdodge(dodge.width=0.5) # position_jitterdodge ?
  ) + 
  geom_line(
    aes(group = supp, color = supp),
    data = df.summary,
    position=position_dodge(width=.5)
  ) +
  geom_errorbar(
    aes(ymin = len-sd, ymax = len+sd, color = supp),
    data = df.summary, width = 0.2,
    position=position_dodge(width=.5)
  )+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this plot was made using `ggpubr` rather than vanilla ggplot. If you want the same look as the linked plot but with jitter-dodged points then you can do:

```r
library(ggpubr)

ggline(df, x = "dose", y = "len", color = "supp", size = 1.5,
       ggtheme = theme_pubr(base_size = 20),
       add = c("mean_se"), 
       add.params = list(width = 0.5),
       position = position_dodge(0.75),
       palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800")) +
  geom_point(aes(color = supp), 
             position = position_jitterdodge(0.5), size = 3)
```

[image]